# Calculate the MSE of T = $\frac{1}{4}\overline{X}$ with respect to $$ where X~$Gamma(4,)$

Tags: probability-distributions, gamma-function, gamma-distribution, mean-square-error

Suppose that $X_1,...,X_n$ is an iid sample that is distributed as $Gamma(4,)$ and suppose that $T = \frac{1}{4}\overline{X}$ is an estimator of $$. How do you calculate $MSE(T; )$?

I don't know how to start this problem because I know $MSE(T; )$ = $Var(T) - Bias(T; )^2$ but I don't know how to calculate $Var(T)$. I also calculated $Bias(T; )$ as follows:

$Bias(T; )$ = $E(T)$ - $$ = $E(\frac{1}{4}\overline{X})$ - $$ = .... = $\frac{1}{}$ - $$ = $\frac{1-}{}$
But I'm not sure if that calculation is even correct. Can someone confirm if it's correct as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**, when you say that the distribution is a $Gamma(4;\theta)$ it is not well determinated because Gamma distribution has different parametrizations.

**Second** when you write

> Suppose that $X_1,...,X_n$ is an iid sample that is distributed as $Gamma(4,\theta)$

I hope you mean that the random sample is "from a population with distribution"... or "where every single observation is distributed as..."

**Third**,

$MSE=VAR + (BIAS)^2$ and not $VAR - (BIAS)^2$ as you wrote: this looks like the great is the Bias, the best is the Estimator...

**Fourth**,

if the problem is only in calculating

$$V(T)=V\Bigg[\frac{1}{4}\overline{X}_n\Bigg]$$

it is simply

$$V(T)=V\Bigg[\frac{1}{4}\frac{\Sigma_i X_i}{n}\Bigg]=\frac{1}{(4n)^2}\cdot n V(X_1)$$

> But I'm not sure if that calculation is even correct

this depends which is the parametrization you used for the [Gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution).  In the link you can find the two more common parametrizations

IMHO, if you use $T$ to estimate the parameter $\theta$ the parametrization that makes more sense is the one in the first column showed in the link, so that $\mathbb{E}[T]=\theta$ and you estimator is unbiased...but this is only my opinion. Only you can know the exact parametrization you have to use.